# Why Pregnant Sita sent to forest without any Mercy?

Tags: ramayana, rama, sita

In [Ramayana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramayana), Why **Pregnant** Sita sent to **forest** without any Mercy?

My Question is different from [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8225/ramayana-why-did-rama-and-sita-wait-so-long-to-have-kids).

Comment: Related [Why did Sri Rama banish Lady Sita when he was a witness of her fire-test himself?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/343/3500)

Comment: i feel this is an interpolated incident along with agni pariksha