# What was the age of Sita in chronological order?

Tags: ramayana, marriage, sita

This question is not duplicate of [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22230/what-was-the-age-of-sita-at-the-time-of-marriage) or [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6525/ages-of-ramayanas-characters)

Can anyone be kind enough to dive deep and provide some input for below questions:

1. What was the age of Sita when first king/prince came to marry her? ([Valmiki Ramayana 1.66.15 & 1.66.16](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga66/balasans66.htm#Verse15))
2. What was the age of Sita during Svayamavar? ([Valmiki Ramayana 1.66.18](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga66/balasans66.htm#Verse18))

**Note:** As per Valmiki Ramayana, Rama and Sita didn't get marry in Svayamvar. The Svayamvar happened before that.

3. What was the age of Sita when Janaka defeated all the kings after they tormented the city of Mithila for 1 year? ([Valmiki Ramayana 1.66.20 to 1.66.24](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga66/balasans66.htm#Verse20))
4. What was the age of Sita when Sudhanva came to marry her? ([Valmiki Ramayana 1.71.17](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga71/balasans71.htm#Verse17))

Comment: Do you think, all the chronology may be derived based on [my answer here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/51148/17833)?

Comment: I don't think so but u can try it.. :)

Comment: https://youtu.be/8RNNTW07sno?t=3075 says she was born as 16years of age..

Answer (score 2):

Impossible to determine because [critical edition](https://bombay.indology.info/ramayana/welcome.html) has excised all the verses indicating the age of Lord Rama and Sita Ji.

The verse in Aranya Kanda indicating the age of Lord is excised in [the critical edition of Valmiki Ramayana](https://bombay.indology.info/ramayana/welcome.html). The Vyasa Mahabharata also doesn't give a clue.

Comment: a fact becomes impossible to determine if some random edition removes mention of it ?