# Was Lord Ram banished after he was married for 12 years?

Tags: ramayana, rama, sita

Please see this verse which says that Goddess Sita resided in Ayodhya for 12 years before she left with Lord Ram and Lakshman
http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/aranya/sarga47/aranyasans47.htm#Verse4

But then see verses later it is mentioned that Lord Ram's  age at time of exile was 25 years and Goddess Sita was 18 years. 
http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/aranya/sarga47/aranyasans47.htm#Verse10

This doesn't make sense as Lord Ram cannot 13 when he got married . Is there some error in translation ?

Comment: why can't be he 13 when was married ? In olden days, both boy and girl were children when they were married, because the word 'marriage' in those days wasn't as polluted as it is these days. even as recent as 100 years back, people got married when they were 10,13, 15 etc. But the girls would only be sent to her husband's home after she attained maturity. Even biologically, the most fertile eggs for women are when she is between 16 & 20. Unnecessarily delaying marriage these days due to societal pressure is causing physical, mental, moral & societal damage due to repression.

Comment: Related [What was the age of Sita in chronological order?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/22338/12304)

Comment: Indeed seems to be the case. I will dig further to understand why child marriage (not consummation) is prescribed in text. Thanks everyone

Comment: @Carmensandiego, because it is important for a sacred rite like marriage to be based on platonic attraction & devotion as the foundation (when kama has not entered the heart yet), and then sexual attraction later in life. nowadays, it's the reverse, and we can all see how well that's working out..

Answer (score 0):

While refusing to send Sri Rama with Sage Viswamitra, Dasaratha says as follows:

> **ऊनषोडशवर्षो** मे रामो राजीवलोचनः | न युद्धयोग्यतामस्य पश्यामि सह
>   राक्षसैः || १-२०-२
>
> "Less than **sixteen years of age** is my lotus-eyed Rama, and I see no
>   warring aptitude to him with the demons.

While dissuading Ravana, from his proposed misadventure of abducting Sita, Mareecha says;

> ऊन द्वादश वर्षो अयम् अकृत अस्त्रः च राघवः || ३-३८-६ कामम् तु मम यत्
>   सैन्यम् मया सह गमिष्यति |
>
> " 'This boy Rama is ***less than twelve years in his age***, unproficient in
>   the use of weapons, and if need be, whatever army of mine is there it
>   will march on along with me instead of Rama.

Maareecha might have lessened the age of Sri Rama further, only to intimidate Ravana.

---

So Sri Rama might be of 13 years of age at the time of marriage with Sita.

Comment: yes, Sri Rama was a child around 13 at time of marriage. As far as Mareecha conversation with Ravana goes valmikiramayan.net in 1-20-2 suggests that Mareecha was talking about Sri Ram's age when he killed his brother and mother