# Was Lord Rama born to a human?

Tags: ramayana, rama

Did Lord Rama take birth from a human body? that is from a human mother since He is God and not an avatar?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  Rama was born from his mother, and he is an avatara of Vishnu.

Comment: See [Putrakameshti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Putrakameshti) on wiki and also [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6527/2995).

Answer (score 5):

When King Dasharatha was performing yagnas, all the deities along with Lord Brahma came for taking 'havish'. While they were waiting, all gods went to Lord Brahma and expressed their fear and torturing faced by them at the hands of Ravana.On hearing Lord Brahma said,( Valmiki Ramayana-Baala Kanda,Sarga 15)

> तेन गन्धर्व यक्षाणाम् देवतानाम् च रक्षसाम् | 
>    अवध्योऽस्मि इति वागुक्ता तथेति उक्तम् च तन् मया || १-१५-१३
>
> When he asked Gandharvas, Yakshas, Gods, Rakshasas should never be able to kill him, I said, "So be it".
>
> न अकीर्तयत् अवज्ञानात् तत् रक्षो मानुषाम् तदा | 
>   तस्मात् स मानुषात् वध्यो मृत्युः न अन्योऽस्य विद्यते || १-१५-१४
>
> The Rakshasa did not include Man, Monkey and Bear because of his disdain for men. As such he is fit to be destroyed by a man and not by any other means.

Further on request of gods Lord Vishnu chose Dasharatha as his father in human world.So it is quiet evident that Rama took birth from a human body.

Check the following link [Valmiki Ramayana - Baala Kanda - Sarga 15](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga15/bala_15_frame.htm) for further details.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Somewhere in your answer you need to mention Rama's mother Kausalya who gave birth to him. _Queen Kausalya gave birth to a son with all the divine attributes like lotus-red eyes, lengthy arms, roseate lips, voice like drumbeat, and who took birth to delight the Ikshwaku dynasty and adored by all the worlds, and who is the greatly blessed epitome of Vishnu, namely Rama._ [[1-18-8, 9, 10, 11](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga18/balasans18.htm#Verse8)]